# How to properly resize imageview on all screens?

Tags: android, blob, drawable, favicon

I'm making mini bookmarks application. The idea is to populate the relative layout with favicons of sites that are stored in browser's bookmark database. I extracted blob images from the database and converted them to drawables using Drawable.createFromStream method. How can I properly sizeup those imageviews because currently they are very small? Another problem that I have is the relative layout. How can I properly populate the horizontal area with icons so when it reaches end of screen they go in new line?

Here's my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    ImageView bookmark;

    scrollView.addView(relativeLayout);

    this.startManagingCursor(cursor);
    Uri Bookmarks = Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI;

    cursor = managedQuery(
            Bookmarks, projection, selection, null, Browser.BookmarkColumns.VISITS + " DESC");

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int idCounter = 1;
        ByteArrayInputStream blobImage;

        do{
           bookmark = new ImageView(this);
           bookmark.setId(idCounter++);

           blobImage = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                   cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(BookmarkColumns.FAVICON)));

           bookmark.setImageDrawable(
                   Drawable.createFromStream(blobImage, "" + bookmark.getId()));

           RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

           if(idCounter > 1) {
               params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, bookmark.getId() - 1);
           }

           relativeLayout.addView(bookmark, params);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
     } 

    this.setContentView(scrollView);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can approach what you're trying to do.

But ImageViews have a scale type, so the image can be forced to scale up but maintain ratio or scale up so the entire view is filled

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

In terms of filling the screen, you'll need to determine either the number of icons per row OR dynamically decide the number of them and size them.